# Can I override Django rendering checkbox inputs inside a label?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to render a form which allows for multiple selections via checkboxes.

I've tried with django-multiselectfield (which I was already using) and the native CheckboxSelectMultiple widget.

If I have a simple form like so:

```
FAVORITE_COLORS_CHOICES = [
    ('blue', 'Blue'),
    ('green', 'Green'),
    ('black', 'Black'),
]

class SimpleForm(forms.Form):
    favorite_colors = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        choices=FAVORITE_COLORS_CHOICES,
    )
```

And if I render with widget tweaks like so:

```
{% render_field form.favorite_colors %}
```

I get the following HTML output

```
<div id="id_favorite_colors">
    <div>
        <label for="id_favorite_colors_0">
        <input class="form-control" id="id_favorite_colors_0" name="favorite_colors" placeholder="Your Name" type="checkbox" value="blue" />
        Blue</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="id_favorite_colors_1">
        <input class="form-control" id="id_favorite_colors_1" name="favorite_colors" placeholder="Your Name" type="checkbox" value="green" />
        Green</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="id_favorite_colors_2">
        <input class="form-control" id="id_favorite_colors_2" name="favorite_colors" placeholder="Your Name" type="checkbox" value="black" />
        Black</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is causing problems for the way I want to render my form. Is there any way I can force Django to output the input and then the label, so the html would be like so:

```
<div id="id_favorite_colors">
    <div>
        <input class="form-control" id="id_favorite_colors_0" name="favorite_colors" placeholder="Your Name" type="checkbox" value="blue" />
        <label for="id_favorite_colors_0">Blue</label>            
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="form-control" id="id_favorite_colors_1" name="favorite_colors" placeholder="Your Name" type="checkbox" value="green" />
        <label for="id_favorite_colors_1">Green</label>            
    </div>
    <div>
        <input class="form-control" id="id_favorite_colors_2" name="favorite_colors" placeholder="Your Name" type="checkbox" value="black" />
        <label for="id_favorite_colors_2">Black</label>            
    </div>
</div>
```

I haven't found an easy answer to this and most of the discussions I've found are from 10 years ago or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this out to find if it will work for you.

Your template will look some thing like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="id_favorite_colors">
        {% for choice in form.favorite_colors %}
        <div>
            <label for="id_favorite_colours_{{ forloop.counter0 }}">{{choice.choice_label}}</label>
            {{ choice.tag }}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And your views.py will look like this

```
def simple(request):
    form = SimpleForm()
    # Any custom logic you want to use for the form
    return render(request, "test.html", {"form":form})
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work really well, so I am accepting your answer, but would you be able to add a little bit explaining why and how your solution works? Is tag the name django calls a checkbox?

Comment: Any chance you could expand your answer with a little bit more explanation?